# How can I wait until Captcha is done in Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, captcha

I'm working on a checkout bot, but hCaptcha is disturbing my plans. Currently I'm using ImplicitWait to allow the captcha to continue for 40 seconds, however upon completion, it seems to prefer to stay on the captcha solving frame.

Here's my code:

```
checkout = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/section[1]/div/form/div[4]/button[1]")

checkout.click()
    
time.sleep(int(task_delay))
        
driver.implicitly_wait(40)
        
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/main/div[1]/iframe")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

Then it just leaves me on this:
[Stuck on hCaptcha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKgzQ.png)

Any idea how I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Understood I think. Switch back to the original frame like in example below

```
def SetPayoutAddr():
    sleep(1)
    browser.switch_to.frame("DOGEFrame")
    payoutaddrbox = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#wpbf_address")
    payoutaddrbox.click()
    sleep(1)
    payoutaddrbox.send_keys(Wallet_address)
    sleep(1)
    browser.switch_to.default_content()
pass
```

Hope that helps!